# Stuck on an integral but very close to the answer

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I want to show that this equation holds for positive a.
$$\int \sqrt{a^2 + u^2}\;du = \frac{u}{2} \sqrt{a^2 + u^2}+ \frac{a^2}{2}\;ln(u+\sqrt{a^2+u^2}))+ C  $$
My attempt is this:
$$u=a.tan(t)\\du=a(1+tan^2(t))dt\\\int \sqrt{a^2 + u^2}\;du=\int \sqrt{a^2 + a^2tan^2(t)}\;du =\int |a.sec(t)|.a.(sec^2(t))\;dt=a^2\int |sec^3(t)|dt$$

And we know that: $$\int sec^3(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}(tan(t).sec(t)+ln|sec(t)+tan(t)|)=I$$
Then I made an attempt to rewrite the right side of my equation.
$$\frac{u}{2} \sqrt{a^2 + u^2}= \frac{a.tan(t)}{2}.|a.sec(t)|=\frac{a^2}{2}tan(t)|sec(t)|=II\\\frac{a^2}{2}\;ln(u+\sqrt{a^2+u^2})=\frac{a^2}{2}.ln(a.tan(t)+|a.sec(t)|)=\frac{a^2}{2}ln(a(tan(t)+|sec(t)|))=III$$
If we multiply I by a^2:
$$I=\frac{a^2}{2}(tan(t).sec(t))\;[which\;looks\;similar\;to\;II]\\+\frac{a^2}{2}ln|sec(t)+tan(t)|\;[which\;looks\;similar\;to\;III]
$$
I'm confused what should I do from now on; My first problem is with absolute values and my second is the fact that III has an "a" element inside the parenthesis of ln but I doesn't. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you could always just take a derivative of the right hand side in stead of trying to integrate the left.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That would be fine. Now help me in this solution

Comment: Your post will look better if you use `$\tan$, $\sec$, $\ln$` etc. instead of `$tan$, $sec$, $ln$`

Comment: Also, you don't have to use the absolute value of the $\sec$, because it is always positive where this integral is concerned.

Comment: @Rollier why is it always positive?

Comment: You want your tangent to vary between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, so you could take $t$ between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. Your cosine, and hence your secans is positive there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural substitution for this integral is $u=a\sinh t$. Then,

$$\int \sqrt{a^2 + u^2}\;du =a^2\int \sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}\cosh tdt=a^2 \int \cosh^2tdt$$

$$=\frac12 a^2\int (1+\cosh 2t)dt=\frac 12 a^2 (t + \frac12\sinh 2t)+C$$

$$=\frac 12 a^2 \sinh^{-1} \frac ua + \frac 12a^2\sinh t \cosh t+C$$
$$= \frac{a^2}{2}\;\ln(u+\sqrt{a^2+u^2})+ \frac{1}{2}u \sqrt{a^2 + u^2}+C  $$

where $\sinh^{-1} x= \ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$ is used.

Edit:

The use of substitution $u=a\tan t$ could be somewhat cumbersome. Continue with

$$I=\int \sec^3t dt= \int (1+\tan^2t)\sec tdt = \int \sec tdt + \int \tan t d(\sec t)$$
$$= \ln(\sec t + \tan t) + \tan t \sec t - I$$

Then,

$$I = \frac12 \ln(\sec t + \tan t) + \frac12 \tan t \sec t + C$$

Then, plug back $\tan t = \frac ua$ and $\sec t = \frac{\sqrt{a^2+u^2}}a$ to recover the given result,

$$a^2\int \sec^3t dt= \frac12a^2 \ln\frac{\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+u}a 
+ \frac12 u\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+ C$$

Comment: hey man thank you, but help me in my solution. I mean put u=a.tan(t). I want to reach the answer with this.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - I added your way in the answer as well.

Comment: you wrote I the same as what i wrote, but why did you remove absolutes?

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - because $\sec t \ge 1$.

Comment: can you explain more. Im newbie in integrals. of course its not true for every t that sec t >=1

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - The range of secant function is $[1,\infty)$, which is always true.

Comment: (sec t = 1 / cos t) and we can put a t such that cos t would be negative. the equation you wrote for secant makes it always positive, but in fact you wrote the equation of $$|sec t|= \sqrt {a^2+u^2} / a $$ by the way what you proved in your second substitution is different from the first. you added a in denominator in the last line but thats not the equation I asked for.

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - I forgot to mention the domain for the substitution is $t\in[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2]$. Regarding $a$, note that $-\ln a$ is just a constant, which is to be absorbed into $C$.

Comment: I got that absorbing point. but doesnt the fact that t∈[−π/2,π/2] contradict that we are calculating an indefinite integral? and if you have time, please explain me in easy language what is the role of substitution domain in general?

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - Sure. The domain of the original variable is $u\in(-\infty,\infty)$, which, via the substitution $u=a\tan t $, is mapped on to $t\in (-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. In other words, for every $u$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$, there is a $t$ in $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. The domain of $t$ is confined within $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$

Comment: I finally understood and said "aha!". I really appreciate your help. Very very much thanks. Farhad from Iran!

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh - You are welcome